# Are we still building the site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In the early days, a stackexchange site often wants questions that are easy to answer with good answers, to as to build the site and attract people. considering the homebrew site is still in beta and has been for a few years, is this something we should be doing?

For example, a couple of days ago I wanted to what a "noble hop" was. A quick web search quickly found answer, but a search here did not. Should the site still be attracting those kind of "useful for future reference" questions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, very much so! Asking these kind of questions makes this site a great resource. You may find the information available via a search but rarely as convenient as the SE format.